# How to keep logging batch file results from repeating

Tags: windows, command-line

Running a .bat file and trying to capture the log file of the results. 
The log file keeps running and repeating the results? What do i do to end it and have it only show once? Thanks.

I put this at the end to capture the log:
2016Q3_TEMP.bat >> Q:\HM\H\2016Q3\log.txt

Comment: Please [edit] and include the batch file code.

Answer (score 0):

What your line is actually doing is recalling the script itself and outputing it to the log file. So you've basically created an endless loop. You have to create another script named differently that calls this one with your line of code.

Example: 
  You should have 2 files.

1. 2016QE_TEMP.bat
2. execute.bat

Contents of 2016Q_TEMP.bat should be your code that you want to execute. 
Contents of execute.bat should be :

```
2016Q3_TEMP.bat >> Q:\HM\H\2016Q3\log.txt
```

This way you will not have a recursive calling of the script.

Comment: @smattiko, good to hear. You can mark this post as answer so others don't try and fix your problem.